# How to add if and else condition or ternary operator for the functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxMrh.png)

Here the 2nd Inputbase should only be displayed if the type is card
The Inputbase is the function of React-beautiful-dnd

I have tried using normally the if and else and ternary but it isnt working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To display the second input use the ternary operator condition like this:

```
{type === 'card'?(
//add your second input here
):(null)
```

and remove the ternary operator logic from InputBase's placeholder